# Unable to create Kafka Redis Sink with Single Message Transformations

Tags: java, apache-kafka, redis, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to create a Kafka Redis sink that deletes a particular key in Redis. One of the ways is to create a Record or Message in Kafka with a specific key and Value as null. But as per the use case, generating the keys is not possible. As a workaround, I wrote a Single message transformer that takes the message from Kafka, sets a particular Key, and sets Value equals null.

Here are my Kafka Connect Confgurations

```
  "connector.class": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.redis.RedisSinkConnector",
  "transforms.invalidaterediskeys.type": "com.github.cjmatta.kafka.connect.smt.InvalidateRedisKeys",
  "redis.database": "0",
  "redis.client.mode": "Standalone",
  "topics": "test_redis_deletion2",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "redis.hosts": "REDIS-HOST",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "transforms": "invalidaterediskeys"
}
```

Here is the code for the transformations :

```
public class InvalidateRedisKeys<R extends ConnectRecord<R>> implements Transformation<R> {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InvalidateRedisKeys.class);

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    @Override
    public ConfigDef config() {
        return new ConfigDef();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> settings) {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    @Override
    public R apply(R r) {
        try {
            return r.newRecord(
                    r.topic(),
                    r.kafkaPartition(),
                    Schema.STRING_SCHEMA,
                    getKey(r.value()),
                    null,
                    null,
                    r.timestamp()
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("a.jsonhandling.{}", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("a.exception.{}", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    private String getKey(Object value) throws IOException {
        A a = mapper.readValue(value.toString(), A.class);
        long userId = a.getUser_id();
        int roundId = a.getRound_id();
        return KeyGeneratorUtil.getKey(userId, roundId);
    }
}
```

where A is

```
public class A {

    private long user_id;
    private int round_id;
}
```

And KeyGeneratorUtil contains a static function that generates a relevant string and sends the results.

I took help from

1. https://github.com/cjmatta/kafka-connect-insert-uuid
2. https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms

When I try to initialize Kafka Connect, it says invalid Configurations. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: You need a `value.converter` even if you will be sending nulls... Can you show the full error?

Comment: This worked. For consuming value as Strings, needed the String Converter. Worked like a charm. Thanks.